# Auditoria y monitoreo en Postgres SQL version 8.1

Tags: postgresql, funciones, trigger

Me encuentro realizando un trigger de auditoria en la cual tengo que almacenar la tabla, esquema y la transacción de la tabla afectada.
Postgres tiene unos parámetros que me muestra esos datos (TG_TABLE_NAME, TG_TABLE_SCHEMA y TG_OP) pero es compatible con versiones de 9.4 en adelante.
 
Mi pregunta es:
¿Existe alguna que yo pueda obtener esos datos en una versión 8.1 de postgres?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según la documentación de la versión 8.1 https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/plpgsql-trigger.html

si se puede obtener pero no con esos nombres, en este caso solo puedes acceder al TG_OP, los demás valores tendrás que obtenerlos desde las variables  TG_RELNAME (TG_TABLE_NAME ), y con TG_RELID   a través de consultas al catálogo de las tablas pg_class   y  pg_namespace puedes obtener el esquema de la variable TG_TABLE_SCHEMA por ejemplo:

```
  Select nspname from pg_class join pg_namespace on pg_class. relnamespace =pg_namespace.oid where pg_class.oid=TG_RELID;
```